# Outbound traffic being blocked for MIP/VIPped servers (Juniper SSG5)

Tags: networking, juniper, ssg5

As we've been having some problems with sporadic packet loss, I've been preparing a replacement router (also an SSG5) for our current Juniper SSG5. I've setup the new SSG5 identically to the old one.

We have a /29 IP range with a single IP setup as a MIP map to a server and two others being used for VIP maps. Each VIP/MIP is accompanied by relevant policies.

Long story short - we tried connected the new SSG5 and some things were not working as they should. No problem, I just reconnected the old one. However, some things are still broken, even when I reconnected the old one. I fear I may have inadvertently changed some settings while browsing through old settings in my attempt to reconfigure the new SSG5 unit.

All inbound traffic seems to work as expected. However, the 192.168.2.202 server can't initiate any outbound connections. It works perfectly on the local network, but any pings or DNS lookups to external IP's fail. The MIP & VIP map to it works perfectly - I can access it through HTTP and RDP without issues.

Any tips on what to debug, or where I've messed up my config?

I've attached the full config here (with anonymized IPs):

```
set clock timezone 1
set vrouter trust-vr sharable
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset auto-route-export
exit
set service "MyVOIP_UDP4569" protocol udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4569-4569 
set service "MyVOIP_TCP22" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 22-22 
set service "MyRDP" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 3389-3389 
set service "MyRsync" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 873-873 
set service "NZ_FTP" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 40000-41000 
set service "NZ_FTP" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 21-21 
set service "PPTP-VPN" protocol 47 src-port 2048-2048 dst-port 2048-2048 
set service "PPTP-VPN" + tcp src-port 1024-65535 dst-port 1723-1723 
set service "NZ_FMS_1935" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 1935-1935 
set service "NZ_FMS_1935" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 1935-1935 
set service "NZ_FMS_8080" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 8080-8080 
set service "CrashPlan Server" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4280-4280 
set service "CrashPlan Console" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 4282-4282 
unset alg sip enable
set auth-server "Local" id 0
set auth-server "Local" server-name "Local"
set auth default auth server "Local"
set auth radius accounting port 1646
set admin auth timeout 10
set admin auth server "Local"
set admin format dos
set vip multi-port
set zone "Trust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "DMZ" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "VLAN" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Untrust-Tun" vrouter "trust-vr"
set zone "Trust" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" block 
unset zone "Untrust" tcp-rst 
set zone "DMZ" tcp-rst 
set zone "VLAN" block 
unset zone "VLAN" tcp-rst 
set zone "Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "Untrust" screen land
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen tear-drop
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen syn-flood
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ping-death
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen ip-filter-src
set zone "V1-Untrust" screen land
set interface ethernet0/0 phy full 100mb
set interface ethernet0/3 phy full 100mb
set interface ethernet0/4 phy full 100mb
set interface ethernet0/5 phy full 100mb
set interface ethernet0/6 phy full 100mb
set interface "ethernet0/0" zone "Untrust"
set interface "ethernet0/1" zone "Null"
set interface "bgroup0" zone "Trust"
set interface "bgroup1" zone "Trust"
set interface "bgroup2" zone "Trust"
set interface bgroup2 port ethernet0/2
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/3
set interface bgroup0 port ethernet0/4
set interface bgroup1 port ethernet0/5
set interface bgroup1 port ethernet0/6
unset interface vlan1 ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip 212.242.193.18/29
set interface ethernet0/0 route
set interface bgroup0 ip 192.168.1.1/24
set interface bgroup0 nat
set interface bgroup1 ip 192.168.2.1/24
set interface bgroup1 nat
set interface bgroup2 ip 192.168.3.1/24
set interface bgroup2 nat
set interface ethernet0/0 gateway 212.242.193.17
unset interface vlan1 bypass-others-ipsec
unset interface vlan1 bypass-non-ip
set interface ethernet0/0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 ip manageable
set interface bgroup1 ip manageable
set interface bgroup2 ip manageable
set interface bgroup0 manage mtrace
unset interface bgroup1 manage ssh
unset interface bgroup1 manage telnet
unset interface bgroup1 manage snmp
unset interface bgroup1 manage ssl
unset interface bgroup1 manage web
unset interface bgroup2 manage ssh
unset interface bgroup2 manage telnet
unset interface bgroup2 manage snmp
unset interface bgroup2 manage ssl
unset interface bgroup2 manage web
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.19 2048 "PPTP-VPN" 192.168.1.131
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.19 + 4280 "CrashPlan Server" 192.168.1.131
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.19 + 4282 "CrashPlan Console" 192.168.1.131
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 22 "MyVOIP_TCP22" 192.168.2.127
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 4569 "MyVOIP_UDP4569" 192.168.2.127
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 3389 "MyRDP" 192.168.2.202
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 873 "MyRsync" 192.168.2.201
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 80 "HTTP" 192.168.2.202
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 2048 "PPTP-VPN" 192.168.2.201
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 8080 "NZ_FMS_8080" 192.168.2.216
set interface ethernet0/0 vip 212.242.193.22 + 1935 "NZ_FMS_1935" 192.168.2.216
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup1 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup2 dhcp server service
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server auto
set interface bgroup1 dhcp server auto
set interface bgroup2 dhcp server auto
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option domainname iplan 
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server option dns1 192.168.1.131 
set interface bgroup1 dhcp server option domainname nzlan 
set interface bgroup1 dhcp server option dns1 192.168.2.202 
set interface bgroup2 dhcp server option dns1 8.8.8.8 
set interface bgroup2 dhcp server option wins1 8.8.4.4 
set interface bgroup0 dhcp server ip 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.116 
set interface bgroup1 dhcp server ip 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.116 
set interface bgroup2 dhcp server ip 192.168.3.2 to 192.168.3.126 
unset interface bgroup0 dhcp server config next-server-ip
unset interface bgroup1 dhcp server config next-server-ip
unset interface bgroup2 dhcp server config next-server-ip
set interface "ethernet0/0" mip 212.242.193.21 host 192.168.2.202 netmask 255.255.255.255 vr "trust-vr"
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" init "AT&F"
set interface "serial0/0" modem settings "USR" active
set interface "serial0/0" modem speed 115200
set interface "serial0/0" modem retry 3
set interface "serial0/0" modem interval 10
set interface "serial0/0" modem idle-time 10
set pak-poll p1queue pak-threshold 96
set pak-poll p2queue pak-threshold 32
set flow tcp-mss
unset flow tcp-syn-check
set dns host dns1 0.0.0.0
set dns host dns2 0.0.0.0
set dns host dns3 0.0.0.0
set address "Trust" "192.168.1.0/24" 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
set address "Trust" "192.168.2.0/24" 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
set address "Trust" "192.168.3.0/24" 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
set ike respond-bad-spi 1
unset ike ikeid-enumeration
unset ike dos-protection
unset ipsec access-session enable
set ipsec access-session maximum 5000
set ipsec access-session upper-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session lower-threshold 0
set ipsec access-session dead-p2-sa-timeout 0
unset ipsec access-session log-error
unset ipsec access-session info-exch-connected
unset ipsec access-session use-error-log
set l2tp default ppp-auth chap
set url protocol websense
exit
set policy id 1 from "Trust" to "Untrust"  "Any" "Any" "ANY" permit traffic
set policy id 1
exit
set policy id 2 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(212.242.193.19)" "PPTP-VPN" permit traffic
set policy id 2
exit
set policy id 3 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(212.242.193.22)" "HTTP" permit traffic priority 0
set policy id 3
set service "MyRDP"
set service "MyRsync"
set service "MyVOIP_TCP22"
set service "MyVOIP_UDP4569"
exit
set policy id 6 from "Trust" to "Trust"  "192.168.1.0/24" "192.168.2.0/24" "ANY" deny 
set policy id 6
exit
set policy id 7 from "Trust" to "Trust"  "192.168.2.0/24" "192.168.1.0/24" "ANY" deny 
set policy id 7
exit
set policy id 8 from "Trust" to "Trust"  "192.168.3.0/24" "192.168.1.0/24" "ANY" deny 
set policy id 8
exit
set policy id 9 from "Trust" to "Trust"  "192.168.3.0/24" "192.168.2.0/24" "ANY" deny 
set policy id 9
exit
set policy id 10 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "MIP(212.242.193.21)" "NZ_FTP" permit 
set policy id 10
exit
set policy id 11 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(212.242.193.22)" "PPTP-VPN" permit 
set policy id 11
exit
set policy id 12 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(212.242.193.22)" "NZ_FMS_1935" permit 
set policy id 12
set service "NZ_FMS_8080"
exit
set policy id 13 from "Untrust" to "Trust"  "Any" "VIP(212.242.193.19)" "CrashPlan Console" permit 
set policy id 13
set service "CrashPlan Server"
exit
set nsmgmt bulkcli reboot-timeout 60
set ssh version v2
set config lock timeout 5
set snmp port listen 161
set snmp port trap 162
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
unset add-default-route
exit
set vrouter "untrust-vr"
exit
set vrouter "trust-vr"
exit
```

Update:
Just as the problem seemingly arose without me having changed any config settings, it disappeared as well. I left the office at 9PM last night, not having found a solution for the .202 server not being able to access the outside. When I showed up this morning, it was working again - and nothing had been touched since I left.

Could this be a matter of connections timing out, new DHCP leases or something like that? We'll be trying to reattach the new SSG5 once again tonight - this time I'm thinking it might actually work, but we're running into the same time-based issues.

Comment: On the main dashboard of the SSG, it should show you how many sessions and resources are being used. Those boxes are quite capable, but an SSG5 certainly is the smallest of them and can't handle alot of traffic. Since its replacing an existing one, I should think you'd be good.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's no shortage of connections - we're no more than ~40 people in the office. None of the resources are above 50%. The problem occurred with 0% utilization as well, right after rebooting the device. I'll see what happens when I reconnect the new device again.

Comment: What is your routing table looks like?